# Placing a HTML snippet on the Top bar in a Magento 2.3.5p2 site

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

How can I place a snippet to be of the top bar of a Magento 2.3.5. p2 site.

This is the area that has the store view drop down, languages drop down, etc.
See below

[image]

Comment: you want to add custom bar above this?

Comment: No ..i want to install a snippet on that bar..

i want  to place this snippet there

https://codepen.io/xavieria/pen/BaKeKxB

Answer (score 0):

You can follow below code to add your bar on top bar in all pages.

In your theme default.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="top.links">
            <block name="top.links.custombar" template="Magento_Theme::html/header/custom_bar.phtml" after="-">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string" translate="false">your-custom-class</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

In your theme `Magento_Theme/header/custom_bar.phtml` create this file

**custom_bar.phtml**

```
<style type="text/css">
    /* place your styles here from your codepan snippet */
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("fs").addEventListener("change",function() {
      const loc = this.checked ? "https://www.google.com" : "https://ask.com/";
      console.log(loc)
    })
</script>
<div class="flipswitch">
    <input type="checkbox" checked="" id="fs" class="flipswitch-cb" name="flipswitch">
    <label for="fs" class="flipswitch-label">
        <div class="flipswitch-inner"> </div>
        <div class="flipswitch-switch"></div>
    </label>
</div>
```